# How to print few lowest numbers from a list?

Tags: c#, numbers

I wrote the following code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int num1 = 0;

    for (int i = -1; i < 10; i++)
    {
        Console.Write("   ");
        if (num1 < -1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You entered a number less than -1, please enter higher number");
            Console.Write("   ");
        }
        num1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    }

    Console.Read();
}
```

the user is able to put any number he want's as long as the number is higher than -1
(the number -1 also can be written by the user)
than i need to print the 4 lowest numbers (and not incluse -1 as one of them), for example:
the user entered: 200, 10, 50, -1, 5, 6, 2, 8, 3
thanit will print: 2, 3, 5, 6

Will appreciate your guys help :)

Thanks

Comment: if the user entered: `200, 10, 50, -1, 5, 6, 2, 8, 3` ... shouldn't it print `-1, 2, 3, 5`?

Comment: @TunZarniKyaw He wants to output lowest 4 numbers that are >= 0.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain ... yes so, i am just wondering what is the purpose of entering `-1`

Comment: Thank you all for the answers, This is something i need for school (i am just starting my way in the programing world) The thing is that i can't use in my code things we didn't learn yet, so i can't use "list" or "count", "var" from you solutions. I need to reach my solution with "for" loop, the user should enter 10 numbers and somehow i should be able to print the lowest number the user entered (without the -1) and i am kind of lost... the code i wrote in my forst comment ket the user enter the numbers as i want, now i stuck with show the 4 lowest numbers. I appreciate all your comments :)

Comment: Please do your own homework.

Comment: i just tried to get your guys assistance for a solution with low options of methods and functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [`List(T).Sort()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0zbh7b6%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to sort the list then get the lowest numbers:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int num1 = 0;
    List<int> numbers = new List<int>();

    for (int i = -1; i < 10; i++)
    {
        Console.Write("   ");
        if (num1 < -1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You entered a number less than -1, please enter higher number");
            Console.Write("   ");
            i--;
        }

        else
        {
            num1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            numbers.Add(num1);
        }
    }


     //sorting
    numbers.Sort(); 
    int amountCounted = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Count && amountCounted < 5; i++)
    {
        if (numbers[i] > -1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(numbers[i]);
            amountCounted++;
        }
        else
            i++;
    }
    Console.Read();
}
```

This code will loop through, check if the number is -1, if it is not, print it and increment the `amountCounted` variable.

Note: `List(T)` requires the `System.Collections.Generic` namespace.

**EDIT**

According to your comment, you would use another variable to hold the lowest value. Examle:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int num1 = 0;
    int lowestNumber = 2147483647;//Max int value:)
    int secondLowest = 2147483647;        

    for (int i = -1; i < 10; i++)
    {
        Console.Write("   ");
        num1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        if (num1 < -1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You entered a number less than -1, please enter higher number");
            Console.Write("   ");
        }

        else
        {
            if (num1 < lowestNumber && num1 > -1)
            {
                secondLowest = lowestNumber;
                lowestNumber = num1;
            }

            else if (num1 < secondLowest && num1 > -1)
                secondLowest = num1;
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine(lowestNumber);
    Console.Read();
}
```

Comment: Thank you all for the answers,
This is something i need for school (i am just starting my way in the programing world)
The thing is that i can't use in my code things we didn't learn yet, so i can't use "list" or "count", "var" from you solutions.

I need to reach my solution with "for" loop, the user should enter 10 numbers
and somehow i should be able to print the lowest number the user entered (without the -1)

and i am kind of lost... the code i wrote in my forst comment ket the user enter the numbers as i want, now i stuck with show the 4 lowest numbers.

I appreciate all your comments :)

Comment: @user3396397 Check my edits. Note that this should be in the [tag:HOMEWORK] and you can infer how to use this methodology for four numbers. You just increase the amount of variables and shift the variable values around some

Comment: Thanks! your edit is great, but that will print only 1 number (the lowest one) instead 4 lowest numbers and i managed to get this far but i am lost with the other 3 numbers i need to show too :)

Comment: @user3396397 You just need to add 3 more variables. It won't be pretty code, but it is supposed to teach you a lesson. I added the code for a second variable to get you started. You just have to shift the values from one variable to another if it is less than. Also make sure to have the `else if { ... }` rather than `if` as if it is lower than the first, it will definitely be lower than the second. `else if` makes sure that won't happen.

Comment: @user3396397 No problem! You can accept my answer to solve the question by clicking the green mark

Comment: This is my first time, and i want to click the green mark but, i don't know any green mark... where is it? (i can't find any green marks)... i found it and marked the V with green :)

Comment: @user3396397 Sorry I should have clarified... Lol it turns green after you click it and welcome to SO!

Answer (score 3):

Filter out the -1 using `Where`, Order the rest with `OrderBy`, and then `Take` what you need.

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", list.Where(n => n >= 0).OrderBy(n => n).Take(4)));
```

Note this is with `using System.Linq;` in your namespaces.

Answer (score 0):

Store of all them in a List only if the number if bigger than -1, an then at the end, do something like:

list is {200, 10, 50, 5, 6, 2, 8, 3};

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", list.OrderBy(x => x).Take(4).Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray<string>()));
```

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

This will give you what you want. Entering `200 10 50 -1 5 6 2 8 3` will print: `2, 3, 5, 6`

```
void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter some numbers seperated by a space");
    Console.WriteLine("");

    var userInput = Console.ReadLine();
    var numbers = userInput.Split(' ');

    var lowestNumbers = numbers.Where(n => int.Parse(n) > -1).OrderBy(n => int.Parse(n)).Take(4).ToList();
    var output = string.Join(", ", lowestNumbers);
    Console.WriteLine(output);
}
```